# Why does the Gmail API returns 401 error?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api

The response after I sent out my batch request to the gmail is the same as described in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors#exponential-backoff):

```
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

My request code is:

```
creds = None

# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.

elif not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    # Save the credentials for the next run.
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)


gmailUrl = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1"

request_header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {creds}", "Host": "www.googleapis.com", "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=boundary"}

body = []

for n in message_Ids:
    boundary = "--boundary\n"
    content_type = "Content-Type: application/http\n\n"
    request = f'GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{n}\n'
    requestObj = boundary + content_type + request + "Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n"
    body.append(requestObj)
body.append("--boundary")

body = "\n".join(body)

response = req.post(url=gmailUrl, headers=request_header, data=body, auth=)
pprint(response)
pprint(response.text)
```

As I managed to somehow get a response from the gmail server I suppose my request got accepted.
But I do not understand why I get the 401 error.
If I send the GET requests as single ones my application works fine.

What do I have to put in the `"Autorization": f"Bearer {creds}"` line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there are reason why you're not using the official library? Can you provide the code related to `creds`?

Comment: There is no batch request in the gmail library for the get-method. See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch

Comment: Batch requests are supported in the library, [ref](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.html#new_batch_http_request). Also, at `"Autorization": f"Bearer {creds}"` you should provide the access token, and you are providing your instance of [credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html) instead. To provide the access token, use `creds.token`, so `"Autorization": f"Bearer {creds.token}"` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I do not quite understand the documentation in the link you provided. I managed to construct a custom batch request myself, but the method you linked to seems to be quite simpler. Unfortunately I don't quite understand the documentation. What is meant with callback or request ID? The example in here: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/batch.html doesn't get me any further.

Comment: I managed to get it work! But I don't seem to really understand it which really bothers me.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how did you make this work? Was changing `creds` to `creds.token` in `Authorization` sufficient to make this work? If not, what changes did you make?

Comment: Well actually I did manage to get a batch request to the API server and accepted in two ways:
1.) I did construct it myself as explained in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch. I needed to post the token directly in here. BUT the token in creds was always said to be Invalid (even if I used the refresh procedure code as explained in the quickstart tutorial). So I needed to request a new token just for this. This is the point I do not understand. Seems to be a bug of some sort. 
2.) I used your approach.

Comment: I solved this as well. Was a mistake on my side as I misread part of the Quickstart-Guide.

Comment: For documentation purposes, please consider providing an answer explaining how you solved this, or I will post an answer explaining that your original issue was you were providing an instance of `credentials` and not an `access_token`.

Comment: I will post an detailed answer after work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671263/why-does-the-gmail-api-returns-401-error#comment119636583_67671263), you were providing an instance of `credentials` in the `Authorization` header:

```
"Authorization": f"Bearer {creds}"
```

You should provide the credentials' `access_token` instead:

```
"Authorization": f"Bearer {creds.token}"
```

#### Reference:

- [google.oauth2.credentials module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments below my question my mistake was that I did provide an instance of the credentials, not the token itself.